# Doctrine2 : MySql required version

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Could someone tell me which version of MySql is required to use Doctrine2 ?

I'm trying to generate my model from an existing database using :

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

But I get an SQL Error, since the following query (called by Doctrine in Symfony2) does not seem to be supported by the MySql version (4.1.14) :

```
SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Required Mysql version is :  `Mysql 5.1`

Comment: Does anyone have a source for this?

Answer (score 5):

The Doctrine project does not explicitly require a certain version of MySQL because it's [database abstraction & access layer](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/) is a thin wrapper around [PDO](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/architecture.html)

So the question is: **What does PDO_MYSQL require?**

From the [PDO_MYSQL docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php):

> PDO_MYSQL is a driver that implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO)
>   interface to enable access from PHP to MySQL 3.x, 4.x and 5.x
>   databases.

PDO_MYSQL (and by extension Doctrine2) can work with MySQL versions as early as 3.x.

But, take note that on the same page it mentions:

> as of PHP 5.4 MySQL client libraries 4.1 and below are no longer supported.

So, if you're using PHP 5.4+ you need to be using **MySQL 5.0** in order to use Doctrine2.

Comment: Up-to-date source, same answer: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/platforms.html#platforms ; Deeper answer https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/orm#v2.5.14